# C# foreach loop doesn't use right index

Tags: c#, foreach, browser

I'm trying to parse my richTextBox and call my function every time I have a new line in my richTextBox.

For example, in my richTextBox I will have :

```
A
B
C
```

For each value, I would like to call my function "removePO()" with the associated value.
But my code only use the last element (in our example, it will just use the "C")

Here is my code :

```
//Global vars
string[] lines;

function a(){
    // .... some stuff

    // I get the value of my rich TextBox
    lines = richTextBox1.Lines;

    //Foreach value, I call my remove function
    foreach(String line in lines)
    {
        removePO();
    }
}

private void removePO()
    {
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_txtSAPOrderId").SetAttribute("value", "00" + line);
        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_btnSearchOrder").InvokeMember("Click");
        while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        SendKeys.Send(username);
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
        SendKeys.Send(password);
        SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
    }

protected void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlElement el = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("content").GetElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            String anchorText = el.InnerText; // will contain "K"
            String url = el.GetAttribute("href"); // will contain "test"
            el.SetAttribute("onclick", "true");
            el.InvokeMember("Click");
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ex Exception : " + ex);
        }
    }

protected void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted2(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            HtmlElement delete = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_lnkDeleteRequest");
            delete.SetAttribute("onclick", "true");
            delete.InvokeMember("Click");
        }
        catch (Exception delete)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Delete Exception : "+delete);
        }

    }
```

Do you have any idea why this is not working?
Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `line` in `removePO()` like that, as it is declared in `function a()` (which doesn't compile). Please show your actual code.

Comment: The function `removePO` does not use `line` as an argument. What exactly are you trying to achieve? What is the scope of the variable `line` in `removePO`?

Comment: `removePO()` doesn't accept any arguments, and you're not sending any to it.

Answer (score 1):

your Method should look like this:

```
private void removePO(string lineOfElement)
{
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_txtSAPOrderId").SetAttribute("value", "00" + lineOfElement);
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_btnSearchOrder").InvokeMember("Click");
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
    //...
}
```

and the call of it is this:

```
//Foreach value, I call my remove function
foreach(String line in lines)
{
    removePO(line);
}
```

then you use always the actual string line from the foreach-Iteration.

Otherwise your line in `removePO` must be a global variable. But your are not assigning `line` from `removePO` in the foreach. thats why it can't work like you have programmed it

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but it still doesn't work.
My program only use the "C" line and it looks like "A" and "B" lines are just ignored

Comment: how much elements does "lines = richTextBox1.Lines;" have? (use the debugger to figure this out)

Comment: "lines = richTextBox1.Lines;" have 3 elements, following the debugger ("A", "B" and "C")

Comment: and you also noticed the change in `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_txtSAPOrderId").SetAttribute("value", "00" + lineOfElement);` ?

Comment: Yes, I changed my code:  
`//Foreach value, I call my remove function  
            foreach(String line in lines)
            {  
                removePO(line);  
            }  

    private void removePO(string iLine)  
        {  webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_cphContent_txtSAPOrderId").SetAttribute("value", "00" + iLine);  

    ....  
    }`

Comment: I think then you have an algorithm problem. this should run fine.

Comment: Pls go through your Code with the debugger and check that everything is working as expected. i can't believe that case A and B is skipped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70299/discussion-between-user3206787-and-jens-horstmann).

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature of `void removePO()` to `void removePO(string ine)` and change the call `removePO()` to `removePO(line)`.